# swift: Font of title in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, navbar

in AppDelegate.swift I have following code:

```
let nav1 = UINavigationController()
    let mainView = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
    nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
nav1.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "JT"
    nav1.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-UltraLight", size: 24)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

But last line doesn't change font of title of nav bar
What i should do?

Comment: Try a smaller font size.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the font didn't change? Many fonts look quite similar.

Answer (score 4):

You can change navigation bar title attributes via Storyboard or try this:

```
nav1.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-UltraLight", size: 24)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own titleView like this:

```
 let label=UILabel(frame: nav1.navigationBar.frame)
    label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.font=UIFont(name: "FONT HERE", size: 27)
    label.text="TITLE HERE"
    label.textColor=UIColor.blackColor()
    for item in nav1.navigationBar.items!{
       item.titleView=label 
    }
```